# Drupal installation not working/ what is .htaccess

Tags: installation, .htaccess, files

I have a lamp server and using drupal. The is on Ubuntu server 14.04. My drupal version is drupal 8.0.0 alpha 15. I followed this guide to install both: http://youtube.com/watch?v=zsPc_Tb8bI8

The problem is that I am running it on a server version, so there is no ui. No browser access in Ubuntu server. I can access my webserver via my host machine of the VM, by typing: 192.168.1.5 
This bring up the default apache page of Ubuntu. When I do 192.168.1.5/drupal, I gives me an error (404 error). I already tried to set the www-data:www-data permission via chown, but this didn't work. Also, while browsing for answers I came across .htaccess file. I remember copying it somewhere, shown in the video. Where should I have copied it and what does it do?

My final(real) question: how do I access the drupal installation from another computer(not localhost). Do I need to set somethi ng in the apche conf? Also, what is .htaccess

Comment: This question relates to your web server setup, not specifically to Drupal, try searching for [how to install Drupal 7 on Ubuntu Linux](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+install+drupal+7+on+ubuntu+linux).

Comment: Its a lamp server, and i did exactly what the video did

Comment: When you do a google search (as suggested above), the first result should be [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Drupal). There is not a video on that link. It is also a well written [Ubuntu Community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community) page that is full of helpful explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in response to your "real" question, a quick [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=htaccess&oq=htaccess) can broadly answer that, but basically it is configuration file to control access of locations on an Apache Web Server.